# Jackson List<Object> to String

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, jackson

I created the following web service just to learn:

```
@GET
@Path("/tmp/uno")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<Object> getData() { 
    KeyValue<Integer, Integer> kv = new KeyValue<>(1, 2);

    List<KeyValue> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(kv);

    **return new ArrayList<Object>(list);**
}
```

I'm doing the cast just for testing purposes and I'm getting the following error:

```
sep 20, 2017 5:53:17 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>.
```

If I don't cast the list

```
@GET
@Path("/tmp/uno")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public **List<KeyValue>** getData() { 
    KeyValue<Integer, Integer> kv = new KeyValue<>(1, 2);

    List<KeyValue> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(kv);

    **return list;**
}
```

I get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "key": {
            "type": "int",
            "value": 1
        },
        "value": {
            "type": "int",
            "value": 2
        }
    }
]
```

I have two questions
1.- Why I cant responde a list of Objects?
2.- Why each property has its datatype in the jSON?

---

The keyValue class is the following:

```
public class KeyValue<X, Y> {
private X key; 
private Y value;

public KeyValue() {
    // Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public KeyValue(X key, Y value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

public X getKey() {
    return key;
}

public Y getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setKey(X key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public void setValue(Y value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

My Jackson dependency is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "real" Jackson library:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or, as it seems you're using Jersey, follow Mkyong example:

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/